# I need a solution for (Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function observeOnOperatorFunction(source) )

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I need a solution for This Error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function >observeOnOperatorFunction(source) {
>          return source.lift(new ObserveOnOperator(scheduler, delay));
>      }' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>   Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function observeOnOperatorFunction(source) {
>          return source.lift(new ObserveOnOperator(scheduler, delay));
>     }' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

I'm trying to retrieve the Transactionlist from the Firebase
 and here is my code

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let n of transactionListRef$ | async">
     <h2>By: {{n.BY}} </h2> 
     <h3>Amount: {{n.AMOUNT}} </h3>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

and here is my ts code

```
export class ListTransactionsPage {
transactionListRef$: FirebaseListObservable <TransactionList[]>

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private database: 
AngularFireDatabase, public navParams: NavParams) {
this.transactionListRef$=this.database.list('Transaction_List');}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using AngularFire.

Your listRef is not an observable now, the last line of your component should read:

```
this.transactionListRef$=this.database.list('Transaction_List').valueChanges();}
```

Comment: when I add valueChanges() I get this (Property 'valueChanges' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>')

Comment: Check the runtime value type of this.transactionListRef$, that should be AngularFireList if you're using v5. Otherwise just make sure your AngularFire dependency is up to date.